# Image preview broken in vs code

Tags: vscode

I am using VS code with the latex workshop extension. Suddenly, without changeing anything on my pc, the image preview at `includegraphics` does not work anymore. It just shows a little rectangular filed with broken text fragments if I hover the mouse over the tex-text. What could cause this? How do I solve this? Is this actually related to the specific extension? There seams to be no issue for this problem on the github page.

Comment: Was this just a one-time glitch, or do you still experience the problem?

Comment: It is still broken, but I noticed that it does not account for all images. But I can not see any logic here (seems independent from file date or date of inclusion in the tex-document etc.)

Comment: neither from file size, file type or non-alphanumeric characters in the path? But yeah, this isn't the most crucial UI, wouldn't be surprised if there are glitches possible

Comment: I include only pictures in pdf format, which was never a problem before. Is the picture preview on hover part of the extension or VS Code itself? Trying to narrow the scope.

Comment: I think it's part of the extension https://github.com/James-Yu/LaTeX-Workshop/wiki/Hover#previewing-graphics